# Ubuntu on Managed VMs using custom runtime

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to deploy a managed vm with Ubuntu instead of Debian? I tried using:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```

at the top of the Dockerfile, but when it deploys and I ssh into from the compute engine console I still see Debian. I am know I am doing something wrong, my app.yaml file has what I think are the correct lines:

```
runtime: custom
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
vm: true
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The image you specify using `FROM` determines the Linux distribution that is used inside the Docker container running in the Managed VM. The VM itself may use a different distribution, and when you SSH from the console, you end up in the VM, not the Docker container.

To enter the container, execute the following command in the VM (`sudo docker ps` will give you the `<container-id>`):

```
sudo docker exec <container-id> -it bash
```

Comment: If I ssh into the machine can I access the Docker container from inside ssh and if you do you know how? Sorry for the beginner questions, just trying to figure this out. Thanks!